# Get last record on GROUP BY using Laravel & MySql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two table (`users` and `messages`) .. I wrote a query to get all  messages that users sent to me or I sent, using JOIN .. to get all the users I have contacted or they did.

as in the code below:

```php
$users = Message::join('users',  function ($join) {
            $join->on('messages.sender_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->orOn('messages.receiver_id', '=', 'users.id');
        })
        ->where(function ($q) {
            $q->where('messages.sender_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->orWhere('messages.receiver_id', Auth::user()->id);
        })
        ->orderBy('messages.created', 'desc')
        ->groupBy('users.id')
        ->paginate();
```

The problem here is when records grouped, I'm getting the old message not the new one according to its `created_at` .. So, I want to get the last record of the grouped records.

Comment: Can you modify the selected fields to add MAX( created_at )?

Comment: @DaveS where? can you explain please ?

Comment: ->select('users.id','messages.body','messages.created_at',DB::raw('MAX(messages.created_at) max_created_at'))

like this? I did it but only it adds another column for the response not getting the message

Comment: Do you have the sender and receiver relationships set up on the `Message` model? Also, is the column definitely `created` and not `created_at`?

Comment: Did the below answer you question or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it would make more sense to make use of Eloquent's relationships here so that you can [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relationships instead of having to use `join` and `group by`:

```
$messages = Message::with('sender', 'receiver')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('sender_id', auth()->id())
            ->orWhere('receiver_id', auth()->id())
    })
    ->orderByDesc('created') // is this meant to be 'created_at'?
    ->paginate();
```